# How to get selected cell of a Kendo UI grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Currently my grid has 3 columns:

```
.Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Bound(x => x.Name);
        col.Bound(x => x.Description);
        col.Command(x => { x.Edit(); x.Destroy(); });
    }
)
```

The grid is set to the following configuration

```
.Selectable(s => s
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
               )
.Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
```

In this case how would I know what cell the user clicked?
My issue is that if the user clicks the Name or Description column then I will perform another event.  However this functionality is being executed if the user clicks the edit or delete button on the grid.  In this case I dont want that to happen.

Javascript:

```
function onChange(arg) {
    var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    // Only call this if the user clicks the Name or Description cell.
        DoSomething(selectedItem.Name);  
};
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you